# How to differentiate error cause of scp?

Tags: scp

When scp fails to fetch a remote file, I would like to know whether it is because a connection problem or the remote file does not exist. Is there a simple way to achieve it?

I know to check $?, but in case it is not zero how to differentiate further the cause of error?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: you can pares the `stderr`, but I don't know what more you want to hear ...

Comment: Thanks. I guess that is as much as we can do.